# Array return in a single input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have two items in this array.

```
$.each(data.recalls,function(i) {
  var recall = data.recalls[i].nnaId;
  var description = data.recalls[i].remedyDescription;
  console.log(recall);
  console.log(description);         
  $('textarea[name="notes"]').val(recall+" - "+description);
});
```

The `console.log()` returns what I need, but when I can only output one result.

**With - `console.log()`**

```
recall - 450
description - description-1

recall - 747
description - description-2
```

**With - $('textarea[name="notes"]').val(recall+" - "+description);**

***only one result***

```
450 - description-1
```

Comment: Robert, you should really consider accepting one of the answers to your question, for this question and the previous questions you have asked. This is how Stack Overflow works. Please read the [tour] and also see [ask] page for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are assigning, not appending the values

```
var result = "";
$.each(data.recalls,function(i) {
  var recall = data.recalls[i].nnaId;
  var description = data.recalls[i].remedyDescription;
  console.log(recall);
  console.log(description);         
  result += recall+" - "+description + " ";
});
$('textarea[name="notes"]').val(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `recall` and `description` are not arrays. Also, you should do it in a different way. Let's say:

```
$.each(data.recalls, function(i) {
  var recall = data.recalls[i].nnaId;
  var description = data.recalls[i].remedyDescription;
  console.log(recall);
  console.log(description);
  $('textarea[name="notes"]').val($('textarea[name="notes"]').val() + recall + " - " + description);
});
```

Either use `array`s, global variable, or `append` the values like how I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct one. But it display all data in a single line. If you want to display a result one by one.

Just add "\n" like below

`result += recall+" - "+description + "\n";`